# How to send Tweet via your iOS App (NOT Twitter)

Tags: twitter, ios9

In my application I need to generate a link and needs to share on Twitter and Facebook. For Facebook I have used its SDK but for Twitter I am not able to find any such SDK which I can integrate in my app and make it able to Tweet it.
On Twitter site I saw REST API but I think that cannot be used for Tweeting. One more thing, I have integrated the Twitter with the help of Social.framework but in case if user hasn't provided his/her details in iPhone then that code won't work and I think if Twitter App is installed in the iPhone we can just launch the app but I cannot pass Data to be Tweeted.
How would you have handled this situation?

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter

Try using one of these URIs. You need to handle the case where the user does not have the app installed also. For that I believe you will want to launch the browser and send a web intent.